# не работает hover circle

Tags: html, css

Не работает hover на circle

```
(https://codepen.io/Veroni1337/pen/wvoXMpQ)
```

есть вот такое модальное окно, на сайте должно срабатывать при наведении на svg

cайт

```
(https://twsc.kz/index.php/geography/)
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: офигеть вы html завалили

Comment: я доделываю после человека

Comment: Есть какие нибудь варианты что можно сделать?

Comment: Если вывести карту за пределы верстки, она же пропадет

Comment: по поводу модалок: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JjbZgzW но карту то можно подключить как image прям внутри svg документа и будет тоже самое тоько что будет меньше кода в 1000 раз

Comment: плюсик поставил - так как вопрос связанный с svg мне понравился

Comment: можно даже сделать так что бы модалка бегала за курсором

Comment: ещё и вопрос про мою Родину ..Казахстан

Comment: Ооу) Спасибо, ваш ответ помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты хочешь, что бы модальное окно появлялось когда наводишь именно на желтую точку, то с card__logo убери cursor: pointer - он отвлекает, и не понятно куда нужно наводить.
во вторых, у тебя в codepen - модальное окно появляется при помощи css, а на сайте при помощи js?
на сайте у тебя выскакивает ошибка:
modal.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at SVGCircleElement. (modal.js:10)

По моему ошибка в том, что он не понимает к какому элементу добавлять класс:
document.querySelector**(`.${trgs}`)**.classList.add("view")

(`.${trgs}`) - это нужно перепроверить.

Так что ищи причину в JS

Comment: Старое модальное окно я вообще убрал, сделал карту заново по совету выше. Теперь новая проблема) text внутри svg не отображается

Comment: Но, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @TricepsSenju что значит не отображается ?

Comment: блин ну есть тег text внутри svg. но на сайте его не видно

Comment: На карте, должно быть как название городов

Comment: @TricepsSenju наверно ни всё перенесли в отдельный файл

Comment: @MaximLensky Не понял( Можете посмотреть на сайте. Если инспектировать, то для них место отведено. Как будто они прозрачны, или под картой отобразились

Comment: @TricepsSenju тексты есть но они ниже слоем чем ваши шэйпы - соберите все text и поместите их перед закрывающим тегом svg

Comment: @TricepsSenju да и у всех text  у вас одинаковые x="530" и y="220"  потому они все будут в одном месте

Comment: @TricepsSenju  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYbBVEz вот так должно быть но только поменяйте координаты для каждого text

Comment: @TricepsSenju и можете вообще убрать тег a из svg а в css написать circle{cursor: pointer}

Comment: @MaximLensky Текст так и не появился

Comment: @TricepsSenju codepen посмотри, вот так должно быть

Comment: Вы меня спасли. Большое спасибо